# How do I go about adding a class to an php echo statement?

Tags: php, html, css

So there is a code snippet at businessbloomer to add a edit cart link to checkout page, however it does not put it in a good placement by default so needs some CSS. I'd like to be able to add a class or id to the snippet so that it is easier to reference, can you advise how to add such to this echo statement, everything I've tried results in an error.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'bbloomer_edit_cart_checkout' );
 
function bbloomer_edit_cart_checkout() {
   echo '<a href="' . wc_get_cart_url() . '">Edit Cart</a>';
}
```

Again, proper credit to https://businessbloomer.com, this is their code not mine. ;)

Comment: `echo '<a class="yourClassHere" href="' . wc_get_cart_url() . '">Edit Cart</a>;`?

Comment: OMG, I was making that so hard! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'bbloomer_edit_cart_checkout' );
function bbloomer_edit_cart_checkout() {
   echo '<a href="' . wc_get_cart_url() . '" class="classname">Edit Cart</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'bbloomer_edit_cart_checkout' );
 
function bbloomer_edit_cart_checkout() {
   echo '<a class="your-class-here" id="your-id-here" href="'.wc_get_cart_url().'">Edit Cart</a>';
}
```

simple. done.